# Rectangle fill with ImageBrush briefly flickers full screen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Building a Universal app in C# / Xaml.

I have a list view with each item containing text etc and a rectangle which I fill with an ImageBrush -> BitmapImage.

The issue is that occasionally the Image will flash full screen when scrolling (seems to render briefly then clip and resize to the bounds of the rectangle.

What's the best way to get around this? I've tried setting the rectangles Opacity to 0 and then making it visible with the ImageBrushes ImageOpened event but this is fired when the image is ready to be rendered - not when it has already rendered on screen.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="ImageHolder"
           Stroke="{ThemeResource ImageBorderBrush}">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush>
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <BitmapImage x:Name="Image" />
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: How are you filling the rectangle with the ImageBrush?

Comment: Update question with current code sample

Comment: Try just adding ClipToBounds=True on your Rect

Comment: I've had weird problems like that with ImageBrush when the shape (rectangle in your case) I was "imagebrush-filling" went off screen a bit. In my case, I could solve that by preventing it to go off-screen. How do you scroll your image?

Comment: Could be a similar issue, the rects are located in the Data template of an ListView, unsure how I could prevent that case happening though